# Can't find div xpath using this template

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I saw this template for finding the message inside a div
Relative xpath: //*[@class='featured-box']//*[text()='Testing']

As you can see in the screenshot, there are no results in the DOM inspect element in google, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or a way to fix this?[image]

Comment: //div[@class='message' and contains(text(),'you do')] try to use this

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: Are you able to filter that div with `//div[@class='message']` alone? That would be my first step. And then check with this `//div[@class='message'][contains(.,'You do')]`. Remember text comparison is  case sensitive in xpath.

Comment: If you want to get message you can try following code 

//div[2][@class='alert alert-error fade in  top-messages']/div[@class='message']

how ever if there are multiple messages fade in one by one then this is useless, you have to get them  in to list. I put dive[2] since i can see two error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the component in the elements window, it should let you copy directly by its Xpath. This should be a last case solution since its not very good practice to access elements like this.

Additionally, the issue could be with the element being in an iframe, which would require you to swap to said iframe before getting the element.

Comment: no iframe issue you can see he is trying to locate an element in chrome dev tool